# Python - One-to-many dictionary mapping

Tags: python

Need a fast implementation of one-to-many `dict` mapping. The task is to convert candidates produced by a generator to its corresponding indices.

A generator can generate several word candidates at each position of a given sentence by looking ahead `n` words see if any appears in the lexicon.

**Input**:

```
tokens = ['by', 'and', 'large', 'multiword', 'expression', 'are', 'a', 'pain', 'in', 'the', 'neck']
```

Word index dictionary, which represents positions of the word in the sentence

```
SlicableDict([(0, 'by'), (1, 'and'), (2, 'large'), (3, 'multiword'), (4, 'expression'), (5, 'are'), (6, 'a'), (7, 'pain'), (8, 'in'), (9, 'the'), (10, 'neck')])
```

**Output**:

```
#candidates
[[('by', 'and'), ('by', 'and', 'large'), ('by', 'and', 'large', 'multiword')], [('and', 'large'), ('and', 'large', 'multiword'), ('and', 'large', 'multiword', 'expression')], [('large', 'multiword'), ('large', 'multiword', 'expression'), ('large', 'multiword', 'expression', 'are')], [('multiword', 'expression'), ('multiword', 'expression', 'are'), ('multiword', 'expression', 'are', 'a')], [('expression', 'are'), ('expression', 'are', 'a'), ('expression', 'are', 'a', 'pain')], [('are', 'a'), ('are', 'a', 'pain'), ('are', 'a', 'pain', 'in')], [('a', 'pain'), ('a', 'pain', 'in'), ('a', 'pain', 'in', 'the')], [('pain', 'in'), ('pain', 'in', 'the'), ('pain', 'in', 'the', 'neck')], [('in', 'the'), ('in', 'the', 'neck')], [('the', 'neck')], []]
# indices
[[[0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]], [[2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]], [[3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6]], [[4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7]], [[5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7, 8]], [[6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [6, 7, 8, 9]], [[7, 8], [7, 8, 9], [7, 8, 9, 10]], [[8, 9], [8, 9, 10]], [[9, 10]], []]
```

**Difficult case**:

```
tokens = ['identify', 'cancer', 'as', 'well', 'as', 'doctor']
```

more than one `as` appears in the sentence, mapping is going to be one-to-many

output:

```
[[[0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]], [[2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]], [[3, 4], [3, 4, 5]], [[4, 5]], []]
[[('identify', 'cancer'), ('identify', 'cancer', 'as'), ('identify', 'cancer', 'as', 'well')], [('cancer', 'as'), ('cancer', 'as', 'well'), ('cancer', 'as', 'well', 'as')], [('as', 'well'), ('as', 'well', 'as'), ('as', 'well', 'as', 'doctor')], [('well', 'as'), ('well', 'as', 'doctor')], [('as', 'doctor')], []]
```

**My attempt**

```
def generate_sent_position_candidates_and_indices(sent, ne_size):

        word2index = SlicableDict({index:word for index, word in enumerate(sent)})
        # print(word2index)

        indices = []
        pos_cands = []
        for i in range(len(sent)):
            # at each position only look at n words ahead, cut the dict
            curnt_dict = word2index[i:i+self.n]

            # one-to-many reversed dict, e.g., {word:[idx1, idx2]}
            reversed_dict = defaultdict(list)
            for key, value in curnt_dict.items():
                reversed_dict[value].append(key)

            # generate candidates at current position
            curnt_pos_cands = list(self.generate_candidates(sent[i:], ne_size))

            curnt_indices = []
            if curnt_pos_cands:
                for mwe in curnt_pos_cands:
                    pool = []
                    tmp = []
                    for word in mwe:
                        word_index = Counter(pool)[word]
                        pool.append(word)
                        tmp.append(reversed_dict[word][word_index])
                    curnt_indices.append(tmp)

            indices.append(curnt_indices)
            pos_cands.append(curnt_pos_cands)


        return indices, pos_cands
```

I've created a `SlicableDict` and a `reversed_dict` at every sentence position, and maintained a `pool` recording words have already seen. Then, use `Counter` to locate the index from `reversed_dict`. I've tested the speed, which is 10 times slower than the one with no returning indices. Is there anything I can do to improve the speed?

**Edited**

The implmentation of `SlicableDict`

```
# ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975339/slicing-a-python-ordereddict
class SlicableDict(OrderedDict):
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        if not isinstance(k, slice):
            return OrderedDict.__getitem__(self, k)
        return SlicableDict(islice(self.items(), k.start, k.stop))
```

**Edited**

Runnable code for test

```
class Test():
    n = 6

    def __init__(self):
        self.test_case()

    def ne_generator(self, tokens, candidates, ne_size=4):
        """Name entity generator extends generated candidates.
           Basically, it generates some word permutations relating to 1st token

        """
        if len(tokens) != 1:
            current_ne = (tokens[0],)
            if len(tokens) < ne_size:
                ne_size = len(tokens)
            for i in range(1, ne_size):
                current_ne += (tokens[i],)
                if current_ne not in candidates:
                    candidates.append(current_ne)
        return candidates


    def generate_candidates(self, tokens, ne_size):

        # ne generator
        candidates = self.ne_generator(tokens, [], ne_size=ne_size)

        return candidates

    def generate_sent_position_candidates_and_indices(self, sent, ne_size):

        word2index = SlicableDict({index: word for index, word in enumerate(sent)})
        # print(word2index)

        indices = []
        pos_cands = []
        for i in range(len(sent)):
            # at each position only look at n words ahead, cut the dict
            curnt_dict = word2index[i:i + self.n]

            # one-to-many reversed dict, e.g., {word:[idx1, idx2]}
            reversed_dict = defaultdict(list)
            for key, value in curnt_dict.items():
                reversed_dict[value].append(key)

            # generate candidates at current position
            curnt_pos_cands = list(self.generate_candidates(sent[i:], ne_size))

            curnt_indices = []
            if curnt_pos_cands:
                for mwe in curnt_pos_cands:
                    pool = []
                    tmp = []
                    for word in mwe:
                        word_index = Counter(pool)[word]
                        pool.append(word)
                        tmp.append(reversed_dict[word][word_index])
                    curnt_indices.append(tmp)

            indices.append(curnt_indices)
            pos_cands.append(curnt_pos_cands)

        return indices, pos_cands

    def test_case(self):
        tokens = ['identify', 'cancer', 'as', 'well', 'as', 'doctor']
        a, b = self.generate_sent_position_candidates_and_indices(tokens, 4)

        assert a == [[[0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]],\
                     [[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]],\
                     [[2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5]],\
                     [[3, 4], [3, 4, 5]], [[4, 5]], []]

        assert b == [[('identify', 'cancer'), ('identify', 'cancer', 'as'),\
                      ('identify', 'cancer', 'as', 'well')],\
                     [('cancer', 'as'), ('cancer', 'as', 'well'), ('cancer', 'as', 'well', 'as')],\
                     [('as', 'well'), ('as', 'well', 'as'), ('as', 'well', 'as', 'doctor')],\
                     [('well', 'as'), ('well', 'as', 'doctor')], [('as', 'doctor')], []]
```

Comment: Would you be willing to provide the code for `self.generate_candidates(sent[i:], ne_size)`? And an example usage of the function

Comment: Thanks for the tips, `candidates` are the results retrieved from a lexicon tree traversal, I forgot to change it. I'll update with a collected test file shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the majoraty of your code. You only need to keep `ne_generator` and to implement a custom [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), that works with any amount.
To make it work the same way as your code, you need to use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest), with custom sentinal values, that we remove.
This can be for example:

```
from itertools import tee, zip_longest

NO_FILLVALUE = object()
def nth_wise(iterable, n=2, fillvalue=NO_FILLVALUE):
    its = tee(iterable)
    for n, it in enumerate(its):
        for _ in range(n):
            next(it, None)
    if fillvalue is NO_FILLVALUE:
        return zip(a, b)
    else:
        return zip_longest(*its, fillvalue=fillvalue)


def whatever(data, size):
    EMPTY = object()
    for items in nth_wise(data, n=size, fillvalue=EMPTY):
        yield tuple(item in item in items if item is not EMPTY)
```

This produces the items:

```
>>> list(whatever('abcde', 3))
[
    ('a', 'b', 'c'),
    ('b', 'c', 'd'),
    ('c', 'd', 'e'),
    ('d', 'e'),
    ('e')
]
```

From this you can then add your `ne_generator` code. Which can be drastically simplified, if you ignore removing duplicates.
Allowing for:

```
def whatever(data, size):
    EMPTY = object()
    for items in nth_wise(data, n=size, fillvalue=EMPTY):
        items = (item for item in items if item is not EMPTY)
        data = (next(items),)
        for item in items:
            data += (item,)
            yield data
```

If you want to add the indexes to each peice of data, then you can just pass the data through `enumerate`. If you want to add your sublist stuff, then you can change the for loop to append to a list instad.

Here's an example of input and output of the above:

```
>>> list(whatever('abcde', 3))
[('a', 'b'), ('a', 'b', 'c'), ('b', 'c'), ('b', 'c', 'd'), ('c', 'd'), ('c', 'd', 'e'), ('d', 'e')]
>>> list(whatever(enumerate('abcde'), 3))
[((0, 'a'), (1, 'b')), ((0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')), ((1, 'b'), (2, 'c')), ((1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd')), ((2, 'c'), (3, 'd')), ((2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'e')), ((3, 'd'), (4, 'e'))]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For test purpose I just put part of the code, complete implementation could be found at [this link][1] [1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183844/python-traverse-lexical-tree-finding-words-in-lexicon, where candidates are generated by NE iteration and tree traversal. If this is the situation, I think we might need to change the indexing method.

Answer (score 1):

It would seem simpler to generate the candidates by just the indices, and translate them into words in the end:

```
def generate_sent_position_candidates_and_indices(self, sent, ne_size):
    indices = []
    pos_cands = []    
    for i in range(len(sent)):
        curnt_indices = [list(cand) for cand in 
            self.generate_candidates(range(i, len(sent)), ne_size)]

        # look up the words by index
        curnt_pos_cands = [tuple(sent[j] for j in sublist) 
                           for sublist in curnt_indices]

        indices.append(curnt_indices)
        pos_cands.append(curnt_pos_cands)

    return indices, pos_cands
```

(This code passes the test)

In this approach, should the `candidates` argument to `ne_generator` be non-empty, it must be converted from words to indices. IMO this would still be simpler overall.